# RegEx to match 123.45 and E123.4 and V12.34

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a RegEx that matches the 3 patterns listed above.  I can somewhat create a working RegEx for any of those 3 but my problem is creating one that works with all 4 of those.  The allowed values are below, where D is any digit and the '.' is never present as a trailing character (i.e. DDD. wouldn't be valid).  Also the V and E refer to those specific characters.

- ddd
- ddd.d
- ddd.dd
- Vdd
- Vdd.d
- Vdd.dd
- Eddd
- Eddd.d

Everything else should be invalid, such as:

- d
- dd
- V
- Vd
- Vdd. (trailing '.')
- E
- Ed
- Edd

I'm not great with RegEx, but I could describe part of this pattern for the entries that start with V as the following:

```
V[0-9]{2,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?
```

I could write very similar statements for the all digit portion of entires and E prefix portion of entries.  The problem is how to combine all 3 into a RegEx that doesn't make my head spin to read.  What's a good RegEx to match all 3 patterns?

EDIT: I forgot to include the format Vdd.dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\d{3}(\.\d{1,2})?)|(V\d{2}(\.\d{1,2})?)|(E\d{3}(\.\d)?)
```

EDIT: Some explanation: I just matched all 3 different formats:

```
\d{3}(\.\d{1,2})?
```

says three digits optionally followed by a period matched with 1 or 2 digits.

```
V\d{2}(\.\d{1,2})?
```

says V followed by two digits with optional period and one or two digits

```
E\d{3}(\.\d)?
```

says three digits followed by an optional period with a single digit

Then I just surrounded each with () and combined them all with | (or).

Comment: put four spaces on the line with the backslash to make it treat it as code instead of MarkDown

Comment: this looks very close to what i need - i forgot to include Vdd.dd as i mention in the edited post but otherwise this looks great!

Comment: Should be fixed for that case now.

Comment: I was wrong. Now it is fixed--I had put \d){1,2} when I meant \d{1,2})

Comment: BTW I think you can spend a lot of time really trying to boil down a regexp into one expression but often it suffices to cover the basic cases and or them together with |--and many times this is much easier to figure out what its doing down the road when you have to modify the code three months after not touching it.

Comment: One more mistake on there-- for the second case add a ?

Answer (score 1):

```
(E\d|(V|\d))\d{2,2}(\.\d)?(?(2)\d?|)
```

E with one digit, or V, or a single digit, followed by two digits, then the usual decimal stuff.

E has to have three non decimal digits, V has to have 2, and digits by them selves have to have three.

If the V or single digit match at the start (I.E. Not 'E') then an extra digit is allowed on the rear.

Comment: E and V can only be followed by 1 digit past the decimal (at least it seems that way from the post). This allows for Eddd.dd

Comment: Fixed it. Now Eddd.d is disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with having three different regular expressions, is there?

```
\d{3}(.\d{1,2)?
V\d{2}(.\d)?
E\d{3}(.\d)?
```

And this will probably be more maintainable in the future.

Comment: i'm using the regex for the mask field of devexpress silverlight controls toolkit, it only accepts a single string.  but yes, otherwise i'd like to keep them separate.

Answer (score 1):

If Eddd would be invalid it would be much easier:

```
[EV\d]\d{2}(\.\d{0,2})?
```

Similarly if Vddd was valid:

```
[EV\d]\d{2,3}(\.\d{0,2})?
```

Matching exactly what you have is a bit harder:

```
(\d{3}(\.\d{1,2})?)|(V\d{2}(\.\d)?)|(E\d{3}(\.\d)?)
```

Make sure you test for exact match otherwise things like

```
V123.1
```

Will match as

```
V12
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it's very helpful.  Yes if those strange cases didn't exist my life would be a bit easier ;)

Comment: Had to edit slightly for my extra case that i forgot but this one completely works.  ty.  (\d{3}(\.\d{1,2})?)|(V\d{2}(\.\d{1,2})?)|(E\d{3}(\.\d)?)